# Spring cloud stream all messages sent to DLQ

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, dead-letter, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm practicing with spring-cloud-stream with kafka-binding with the following application:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: single;react
    stream:
      bindings:
        single-in-0:
          destination: single-in
          group: single-in
        single-out-0:
          destination: single-out
        react-in-0:
          destination: react-in
          group: react-in
        react-out-0:
          destination: react-out
      kafka:
        default:
          consumer:
            enableDlq: true
            dlqName: dlq
        binder:
          brokers: 192.168.153.133:9092
          autoAddPartitions: true
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    
    @Bean
    public Function<String,String> single() {
        return msg -> {
            if ("EXCP".equalsIgnoreCase(msg)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Received bad massage");
            }
            return "OK: " + msg;
        };
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Function<Flux<String>,Flux<String>> react() {
        return fluxMsg -> {
            return fluxMsg.map(msg -> {
                if ("EXCP".equalsIgnoreCase(msg)) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Received bad massage");
                }
                return "OK: " + msg;
            });
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see the application is very simple: if the message received is "EXCP" it throws an Exception, otherwise it publishes an "OK" message.

What's not clear to me is why in case of a bad message read from "react-in" then every message read from this topic goes in the DLQ topic. For example:

1. Write "test-1" to "react-in" -> Got "OK: test 1" in "react-out"
2. Write "test-2" to "react-in" -> Got "OK: test 2" in "react-out"
3. Write "EXCP"   to "react-in" -> Got "ECP" in "dlq"
4. Write "test-3" to "react-in" -> Got "test 3" in "dlq"

I would have expected the last message to be published in the "react-out" topic and not in the "dlq" one.
Here the logs:

```
...
ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 100
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.153.133:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = react-in
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

2020-08-13 09:59:10.622  INFO 17688 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.5.0
2020-08-13 09:59:10.622  INFO 17688 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 66563e712b0b9f84
2020-08-13 09:59:10.622  INFO 17688 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1597305550622
2020-08-13 09:59:10.623  INFO 17688 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-react-in-4, groupId=react-in] Subscribed to topic(s): react-in
2020-08-13 09:59:10.624  INFO 17688 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService
2020-08-13 09:59:10.631  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-single-in-2, groupId=single-in] Successfully joined group with generation 8
2020-08-13 09:59:10.637  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-single-in-2, groupId=single-in] Adding newly assigned partitions: single-in-0
2020-08-13 09:59:10.648  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-single-in-2, groupId=single-in] Setting offset for partition single-in-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=18, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[192.168.153.133:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
2020-08-13 09:59:10.658  INFO 17688 --- [           main] s.i.k.i.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : started org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter@de8039f
2020-08-13 09:59:10.668  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-react-in-4, groupId=react-in] Cluster ID: UzQ_A2bBRdOuprgdvSEIZg
2020-08-13 09:59:10.676  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-react-in-4, groupId=react-in] Discovered group coordinator 192.168.153.133:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2020-08-13 09:59:10.677  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-react-in-4, groupId=react-in] (Re-)joining group
2020-08-13 09:59:10.689  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-react-in-4, groupId=react-in] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group
2020-08-13 09:59:10.689  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-react-in-4, groupId=react-in] (Re-)joining group
2020-08-13 09:59:10.699  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-react-in-4, groupId=react-in] Finished assignment for group at generation 4: {consumer-react-in-4-7ca5b03b-bc58-4af0-b4e5-c0666fc2f05a=Assignment(partitions=[react-in-0])}
2020-08-13 09:59:10.723  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-react-in-4, groupId=react-in] Successfully joined group with generation 4
2020-08-13 09:59:10.723  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-react-in-4, groupId=react-in] Adding newly assigned partitions: react-in-0
2020-08-13 09:59:10.726  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-react-in-4, groupId=react-in] Setting offset for partition react-in-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=51, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[192.168.153.133:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
2020-08-13 09:59:10.726  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$1  : react-in: partitions assigned: [react-in-0]
2020-08-13 09:59:10.728  INFO 17688 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 4.473 seconds (JVM running for 5.039)
2020-08-13 09:59:10.753  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$1  : single-in: partitions assigned: [single-in-0]
2020-08-13 09:59:23.925  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.153.133:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = producer-3
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer

2020-08-13 09:59:23.932  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.5.0
2020-08-13 09:59:23.932  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 66563e712b0b9f84
2020-08-13 09:59:23.932  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1597305563932
2020-08-13 09:59:23.944  INFO 17688 --- [ad | producer-3] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-3] Cluster ID: UzQ_A2bBRdOuprgdvSEIZg
2020-08-13 09:59:31.919  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'application.react-in-0' has 0 subscriber(s).
2020-08-13 09:59:34.922 ERROR 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.react-in-0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[4], headers={kafka_offset=54, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@60e67748, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=react-in, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1597305564033, contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=react-in}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[4], headers={kafka_offset=54, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@60e67748, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=react-in, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1597305564033, contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=react-in}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:384)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:443)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:417)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1878)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1860)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1797)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1737)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1634)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1364)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:988)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[4], headers={kafka_offset=54, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@60e67748, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=react-in, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1597305564033, contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=react-in}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    ... 27 more

2020-08-13 09:59:34.925  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.153.133:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = producer-4
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer

2020-08-13 09:59:34.929  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.5.0
2020-08-13 09:59:34.930  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 66563e712b0b9f84
2020-08-13 09:59:34.930  INFO 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1597305574929
2020-08-13 09:59:34.943  INFO 17688 --- [ad | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Cluster ID: UzQ_A2bBRdOuprgdvSEIZg
2020-08-13 09:59:39.770 ERROR 17688 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.react-in-0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[6], headers={kafka_offset=55, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@60e67748, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=react-in, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1597305568884, contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=react-in}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[6], headers={kafka_offset=55, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@60e67748, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=react-in, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1597305568884, contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=react-in}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:384)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:443)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:417)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1878)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1860)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1797)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1737)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1634)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1364)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:988)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[6], headers={kafka_offset=55, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@60e67748, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=react-in, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1597305568884, contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=react-in}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    ... 27 more
```

Funny to note that the "single" function behave as I expected:

1. Write "test-1" to "single-in" -> Got "OK: test 1" in "single-out"
2. Write "test-2" to "single-in" -> Got "OK: test 2" in "single-out"
3. Write "EXCP"   to "single-in" -> Got "ECP" in "dlq"
4. Write "test-3" to "single-in" -> Got "OK: test 3" in "single-out"

Can someone explain me why with the reactor implementation all messages are published in the dql and what means the "Dispatcher has no subscribers" error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would have failed because the reactive stream is closed for all other event consumption as it has failed during the process of first event during which the exception is thrown, so the other events consumed are not able to processed, because of that you are receiving the error "Dispatcher has no subscribers"

1. use onErrorContinue

```html
  @Bean
  public Function<Flux<String>,Flux<String>> react() {
    return fluxMsg -> {
      return fluxMsg.map(msg -> {
        if ("EXCP".equalsIgnoreCase(msg)) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Received bad massage");
        }
        return "OK: " + msg;
      }).onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> logger.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable));
    };
  }
```

2. Delete all the consumer groups and topics and restart the application